# GoogleMaps.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm having some issues integrating Google Maps into my iOS 8 Today Extension. The full source for this particular issue is available at: http://github.com/seanoshea/BluePlaquesLondon. The issue in question happens on the ios8 branch.

I'm using cocoapods to bring the Google Maps API into a Framework which is shared between my application and my Today Extension target. My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

xcodeproj 'BluePlaquesLondon.xcodeproj'

link_with ['BluePlaquesLondon', 'BluePlaquesLondonFramework']

pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.10.1'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.9'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'
pod 'IntentKit'
pod 'HCViews'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
pod 'iRate'
pod 'iOS-KML-Framework', :git => 'https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework.git'
```

The BluePlaquesLondonFramework target has a reference to:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

and if I try to build the Framework on its own, it works fine. But, when I try to build the main target which references the Framework, it doesn't work at all. I just get a linker errors saying that the GoogleMaps.h cannot be found.

Any ideas on what I could try to resolve this issue?

Sean